# pip install on mac runs into version error

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm trying to install a python package with pip, but it thinks I have a different Mac version than I actually do:

```
pip install root_numpy

Collecting root-numpy
Using cached root_numpy-4.4.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: root-numpy
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for root-numpy ... error
Complete output from command /Users/mattzhang/py3_kernel/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/38/2_qkncsd1hlgd2871lnmrgw80000gn/T/pip-build-xexox4xy/root-numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/38/2_qkncsd1hlgd2871lnmrgw80000gn/T/tmpawn1rjqlpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/root_numpy
copying root_numpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/root_numpy
copying root_numpy/_array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/root_numpy

...

clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
```

The issue here is that I'm using Yosemite version 10.10.5, but pip thinks I'm using 10.6. What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set deployment target
`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10` and then again do `pip install root_numpy`.